# Get subset of rows where any column contains a particular value

Tags: python, pandas, sas, statistics

I have a very large data file (foo.sas7bdat) that I would like to filter rows from without loading the whole data file into memory. For example, I can print the first 20 rows of the dataset without loading the entire file into memory by doing the following:

```
import pandas
import itertools

with pandas.read_sas('foo.sas7bdat') as f:
    for row in itertools.islice(f,20):
        print(row)
```

However, I am unclear on how to only print (or preferably place in a new file) only rows that have any column that contain the number 123.1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has the ability to pull dataframes one chunk at a time.  Following the trail of read_sas() documentation to "chunksize" I came across this:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

```
for chunk in pd.read_sas('foo.sas7bdat', interator=True, chunksize=100000):
    print(chunk)
```

This would get chunks of 100,000 lines.
As for the other problem you would need a query.  However I don't know the constraints of the problem.  If you make a Dataframe with all the columns then you still might overflow your memory space so an efficient way would be to collect the indexes and put those in a set, then sort those and use .iloc to get those entries if you wanted to put those into a Dataframe.

You may need to use tools that take this into account.  Dask is a good alternative for use on clusters.